# Find and determine the type of all singularities of function $f(z)=\frac{z-1}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{z})\sin(\pi z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find and determine the type of all singularities of function $$f(z)=\frac{z-1}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{z})\sin(\pi z)}$$

I found that the set of the singularities is following:

$$S=\{\frac{1}{k}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cup\{l:l\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

How can I proceeed further? I barely have any idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{z\to\frac1k}\left(z-\frac1k\right)f(z)\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\frac1{-\frac\pi{1/k^2}}\frac{\frac1k-1}{\cos\frac\pi{1/k}\sin\frac{\pi}k}=(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\frac1{k^2}-\frac1k}{\pi\sin\frac{\pi}k}=(-1)^{k-1}\frac{1-k}{k^2\pi\sin\frac{\pi}k}$$

Likewise:

$$\lim_{z\to k}\left(z-k\right)f(z)\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\frac{k-1}{\pi\sin\frac{\pi}k\cos k\pi}=(-1)^k\frac{k-1}{\pi\sin\frac{\pi}k}$$

Watch closely the case $\;k=1\;$ !

Comment: what kind of singularities they are? and why did you attack in this way?

Comment: Since sine has simple poles the function has at most simple poles. The attack if because *by definition* function $\;f\;$ has a pole of multiplicity $\;m\;$ at $\;z_0\;$ if the following limit exists finitely $$\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)^mf(z)$$

Comment: thanks for making me realize this god given fact on poles

Answer (score 1):

First recall that $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}=1$.

Then use this to create a similar limit at each of the singularities.

Use these limits to show that the order of the singularities as zeros of the sines are one.

Study the special case of the $z=0$ (and $z=\infty$ if your course studies it), where other singularities accumulate.

Study the special case of $z=1$ where the numerator helps cancelling the order of the singularity.

Comment: z=1 is also special, isnt it?